# How to start React app on non-index.html page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I want my app's landing page to be a basic HTML file for SEO reasons and performance reasons.  So index.html should be static HTML, then when clicking on a link, it takes the user to the React app proper.

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-a-react-app-from-scratch-f3c693b84658), to setup a React app from scratch, however when clicking on the App link, the app doesn't start.  Any help is appreciated.

webpack-config

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

/*entry: "./src/index.js",*/

module.exports = {
  entry: "./public/index.html",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['env'] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true
  },
  plugins: [ new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() ]
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Taduun</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="app.html">To the APP</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>React Starter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is that `./public/index.html` value for entry property in webpack-config.js?

Comment: use some ssr or gatsby for react seo ?

Comment: @Majid It was my uneducated attempt at solving this issue.

Comment: @xadm Could you elaborate on how those tools can help?  I'm very new to React.  Typically I've only used create-react-app in the past to start React projects.

Comment: google for 'react seo ssr' ??

Comment: @xadm.  That's not helpful.  Even if it does server side rendering, there is still some javascript bundled with the application that needs to be delivered.  I'm trying to keep the landing page as small and succinct as possible to ensure a good experience.

Comment: index.html served from public (server root) - path/url `../dist/bundle.js` probably not accessible in browser

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `webpack-config` file. You should change the entry to
 `entry: "./src/index.js"` as that is the one in the post you have shared.

You have misunderstood to the `entry` in the file. This entry is note the entry file of your local server rather it is the entry for webpack to build the `bundle.js` file. You should consider looking webpack documentation for more information https://webpack.js.org/configuration/.

So your new config file is

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['env'] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true
  },
  plugins: [ new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() ]
};
```